# Simplifying expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression:

```
(1 - a) (H - 3 L*r + L)
```

and I would like to `simplify' this to

```
(1 - a) (H - L(3 r +1))
```

I thought that maybe **Simplify** or **Collect** could work, but to no avail.

What's the right function to achieve this?

Comment: `expr = (1 - a) (H - 3 L*r + L); Collect[#, L] & /@ expr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map [`HornerForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HornerForm.html) to each factor:

```
expr = (1 - a) (H - 3 L*r + L); 

HornerForm /@ expr
```

> ```
> (1 - a) (H + L (1 - 3 r))
> ```